# Can't access to label in prototype cell in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

This is my code :

```
@implementation NViewController{
    NSArray *recipes;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    recipes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Egg Benedict", @"Mushroom Risotto", @"Full Breakfast", nil];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [recipes count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"RecipeCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

i add a label to content view in prototype tableviewcell but can't access to it (txtname).
please show me a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add a label to your prototype cell, and wish to access that label through your code, you need to do the following as well:

- Define a class for your custom cell, extending `UITableViewCell`
- Add an `IBOutlet` property `txtname` for your label in the custom cell class
- Establish a connection between the outlet property and the label (e.g. by command-dragging)
- Set the type of your custom cell to the properties of your prototype cell in the storyboard
- Change the code to reference your custom cell type instead of `UITableViewCell`

The last step changes your code as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"RecipeCell";
    MyCustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[MyCustomTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    cell.txtname.text = [recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: thanks for you answer.i am newbie to xcode. how can i define class for prototype cell?

Comment: @nmokkary In the usual way - in Xcode's menu, choose New..., in the window that opens choose Objective-C class, enter a name, and enter `UITableViewCell` for the "base class". Click the "OK" button to finish the process. Now open the properties of the cell, and pick the class name from the drop-down to connect the cell of the storyboard to the class in your code. Finally, command-drag the label to the class file to create `IBOutlet`.

Answer (score 4):

You can set up tag (for example 100) to the label in storyboard and in cellForRowAtIndexPath: method before you return cell you cat get reference to that label by tag

```
UILabel *taggedLabel =(UILabel*) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:100]; 
taggedLabel.text = [recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```